# How do we use the --pdf flag for generating documentation?

Tags: kframework

The video tutorial in http://www.kframework.org/index.php/Lesson_4,_LAMBDA:_Generating_Documentation;_Latex_Attributes suggests that we should use `kompile lambda --pdf`, but when I run it I got the following error:

```
[Error] Critical: Unknown option: --pdf (Unknown option: --pdf)
```

The `kdoc --help` option also result in a `Command 'kdoc' not found` error.

How do I correctly use this option to generate the formatted K definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kdoc` functionality (and `--pdf`) has not worked for quite some time.

If you want LaTeX ASTs output for given individual terms, you can use `--output latex` for any of `kast`, `krun`, or `kprove`. Unfortunately this does not work for entire definitions yet, and will not auto-format for you (it only outputs an AST, you'll still need to tell LaTeX how to render the nodes in said AST).